# How to get a script to read and write a file?

Tags: python

I'm completing exercise 16 from Learn Python the Hard Way and it's asking this question:

> Write a script similar to the last exercise that uses `read` and `argv` to
>   read the file you just created.

I'm attempting to use the 'read' function in order to have the script automatically run and display the text file that the script creates. But nothing shows up when I run everything, it's just an extra blank space before "close it". How do I get it to display anything?

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Erase %r" % filename
print "hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file."
target.truncate()

print "Need 3 lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "Write these to a file"

target.write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(line1, line2, line3))

print txt.read()

print "Close it."
target.close()
```

Comment: `target.close()` flushes the file buffer and writes it to the disk. It's possibly still in memory and not yet on the disk when you call `txt.read()`

Comment: FYI: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: Thanks, I think the close and truncate functions have something to do with it. I'll dig more.

Comment: is keeping the same file open twice something that book is teaching you?  Poor practice IMO.

Comment: went and looked at the exercise, no they do not open twice.  They also note that `truncate` is not necessary.  (So why introduce a method that superfluous and  rarely ever used??)

Comment: I added this part:    print txt.read()    in my attempt to get it to spit out the file contents.

Comment: I commented out the truncate function, definitely not needed. Seems people aren't very fond of this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the file after writing and then open it again for reading:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "Erase %r" % filename
print "hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
with open(filename, 'w') as target:

    print "Truncating the file."
    target.truncate()

    print "Need 3 lines."

    line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
    line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
    line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

    print "Write these to a file"

    target.write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(line1, line2, line3))

txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()

print "Close it."
target.close()
```

The second version (without "with as" structure):

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "Erase %r" % filename
print "hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file."
target.truncate()

print "Need 3 lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "Write these to a file"

target.write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(line1, line2, line3))
print "Close it."
target.close()

txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

Comment: And use the "with open(filename, 'w') as target:" structure, because it is much safer.

Comment: note that `open`  `w` on an existing file truncates the file already so `truncate` is redundant  (unnecessary)

Comment: I imagine a lot of this is new news since the book was written with Python 2 in mind. Honestly I'm very new to programming and just trying to stick to a single source for once. The above structure isn't working properly, I'll keep debugging.

Comment: File "ex16a.py", line 14
    print "Need 3 lines."
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: I've added another example, try it.

Comment: @AlexandrAbramov    You people are awesome, thanks so much. That first structure must not work in the version of Python I'm using.